# add together numbers from an array that have 3 factors only

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

`array = [3,6,7,9,21,100]` so only 6 and 21 should be added together

below is what I have tried

```
def getFactors(n):
# Create an empty list for factors
factors=[];

# Loop over all factors
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if n % i == 0:
        factors.append(i)

# Return the list of factors
return factors

# Call the function with a given value
print (getFactors(256))
```

Comment: Format your code correctly please.

Comment: This has been formatted

Comment: formatting is not complete. And how is this code attempting to solve the problem?

Comment: Please explain what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Can you explain how 6 and 21 have 3 factors ?
Factors for 6 = 1,2,3,6 (4 factors)
Factors for 21 = 1,3,7,21 (4 factors)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def lenfactors(n):
   return len(set((reduce(list.__add__, ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))))-1 

num_list=[3,6,7,9,21,100]
fac_len = 3
pd.DataFrame(num_list) 
df['len_factors'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: lenfactors(x))
print(sum(list(df[0][df['len_factors'] == fac_len])))
# 27
```

```
list(df[0][df['len_factors'] == fac_len])                                                                                                                                                       
# [6, 21]
```